# Spring Boot + Hibernate: Custom fields on auto-generated pivot tables

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

In a Model I have:

```
public class House {
    ....
    ....
    @OneToMany
    @Nullable
    private List<Person> people;
```

When running the Spring Boot application, I will see thee tables created. One for the `House` model, one for the `Person` and another one, automatically generated pivot table to keep relationship information `House` and `Person`.

My question is: what If I wanted to add a `created_at` field onto the rows of the pivot table, so that for each association of `House` to `Person` I'd be able to tell *when* it was created.

I could not find a way to do that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an additional entity for the join table (House_Person). Inside of the new entity you declare the additional fields you need like created_at. Lastly you only need to link your both entitys to the new entity with @ManyToOne:

**House_Person Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUSE_PERSON")
public class HousePerson {
  ...

  private Person person;
  private House house;
 
  // additional fields
  private Date created_at;
  
  ...

  private Person person;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
  public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
  }

  private House house;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "HOUSE_ID")
  public House getHouse() {
    return house;
  }
}
```

Have a look at this example here I hope that describes it well:
[codejava.net/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example)